# save xgb model trained using caret to database

Tags: r, sqlite, r-caret, xgboost

I trained a xgb model using the caret package with traincontrol. I serialized and converted to character before saving the model to local SQLite database. I was able to save it. But while retrieving it from database and unserializing it, it throws an error  unserialize(charToRaw(xgbModel))

Error in unserialize(charToRaw(selected_model$Model)) : 
  ReadItem: unknown type 57, perhaps written by later version of R

Answer (score 0):

To save the xgboost model trained by caret you need to save to raw. Here is an example:

```
library(mlbench) #for the data set
library(caret)
library(xgboost) 

data(Sonar)  

caret_model <- train(x = Sonar[,1:60],
                     y = Sonar$Class,
                     method = "xgbTree",
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 2),
                     tuneLength = 2)
```

save the raw model:

```
raw_model <- xgb.save.raw(caret_model$finalModel)
```

serialize that and save it to the local db. When you unserialise:

```
caret_model2 <- xgb.load(raw_model)

preds <- predict(caret_model2, as.matrix(Sonar[,1:60]))

head(preds)
#output
0.08729284 0.04738589 0.05628103 0.04275921 0.02574497 0.00655277
```

then you can use `caret_model2` to predict.

This is mentioned [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/vignettes/xgboostPresentation.html) under "save and load models".